# Complexity of a maximum algortihm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, max, complexity-theory

I have a basic maximum algorithm like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
    if(a[i-1]>a[i]){
        // Switch a[i-1] with a[i]
        int temp = a[i-1]; a[i-1] = a[i]; a[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

And the task is to find the average number of times the switch happens. The answer should be `log(n)`, but I don’t understand how.

So with the best case, it happens 0 times (if the array is already sorted), and the worst case it happens `(n-1)` times (if it is sorted decreasingly).

I tried to make random permutation of *n* numbers and find the average, but I find that the number of switches on average is almost starting to creep to about *n*. What is the explanation for this complexity? I have racked my brain about this too long.

Comment: Please provide a source for the claim *"The answer should be log(n)"*.

Comment: Is that actually the code that came with the log(n) claim? Or did you make up that code yourself independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that the average number of times the swap happens would be log is false. However, if we would count the average number of times the swap **doesn't** happen, it ends up as O(log).

#### Proof

Let's assume the array has length , and has distinct integer values between 0 and −1 (included).

The maximum number of swaps is −1.

The probability of *not* having a swap in the first iteration is 1/2

For the second iteration we can reason as follows:

The distribution of the first two values is assumed to be an even distribution and so the expected  lowest value is ~(1/3) and the expected greatest value is ~(2/3). As after the first iteration that  greatest value must sit at index 1, we have an expected probability of 1/3 of not swapping with the next value in the array.

Similarly for the third iteration we can say there is a 1/4 probability of not swapping...

And so it continues until the last iteration, where we will have at index `i-1` either the greatest value (greatest probability) or a tiny probability that the greatest value sits already at index `i`. The number of cases where the latter is the case is 1/<sup>th</sup> of the total number of cases.

Therefore the expected total number of non-swaps is a series with −1 terms:

1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/

If we would prefix this with an extra term 1/1, then this is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) that asymptotically approaches log. For asymptotic complexity the missing term 1 is not relevant.

So we can conclude that the number of times there is **no**(!) swap, has a complexity of O(log). The number of swaps has a complexity of O(−1−log) which is O().

Answer (score 0):

That is not a "max algorithm". It's a single swipe of bubble sort or insertion sort, where the first swap can happen with a probability of 1/2 and the last with a probability closer to one (as the comparisons are not independent).

If I were to guess what kind of max algorithm could give the average complexity of O(log N) swaps, it would probably mean the number of expected cases, when cumulative maximum is updated.

In that algorithm the worst case is still O(N) and best case O(1). There will be anyway some large value reasonably early in the array with high probability, which will block further swaps. I don't have a proof, but enumerating some small arrays (size 4, size 8) shows O(log2(N)) trend in the number of swaps:

With octave:

```
mean(sum(diff(cummax(perms(1:4)')) ~= 0))+1
ans = 2.0833
octave:2> mean(sum(diff(cummax(perms(1:8)')) ~= 0))+1
ans = 2.7179
```

To try `perms(1:16)` is unfeasible (with 20922789888000 permutations); but this could be of course simulated with Monte-Carlo algorithm for much larger arrays.